# German passive construction with 'Spaß' and 'machen'

Tags: passive

In German, is there a correct way of saying *we have lots of fun* using the passive voice?

I have trouble understanding the grammar behind this, because German used *Spaß* with *machen* for *to be fun*, rather than *sein*. So how would we turn this in passive voice? Is the following correct?

> Es wird viel Spaß von uns gemacht.

(*lit.* There is lots of fun made by us).

Comment: Whatever you trying to say, I think it's not idiomatic. Idiomatic would be: "Wir haben Spaß (gehabt)", "Wir machen Spaß (haben Spaß gemacht)", "Das macht Spaß (hat Spaß gemacht)"

Comment: "we have lots of fun" has no passive in it. Also, what is "sein" + "machen"

Comment: I think the question is about correct usage of *"machen"* for passive voice, and not about the translation itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*We have lots of fun* is translated as *Es macht uns viel Spaß* or *Wir haben viel Spaß*. This is not a passive construction - neither in your English samples nor in the translation.

Comment: Es ist spaßig für uns? Wir sind spaßig?

Comment: Both are not passive voice. *Wie sind spaßig* means *We are funny* and *Es ist spaßig für uns* means *It is fun for us*. Not exactly the same thing as *Es macht uns viel Spaß*, while the latter is close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aktiv: Es macht uns viel Spaß.
2. Passiv: Es wird viel Spaß von uns gemacht.

Aber: "Wir haben viel Spaß" ist intransitiv - Weil: "Der Spaß wird von uns gehabt" zwar schön ist, aber nicht erlaubt.

Im Wörterbuch steht hinter den Verben *trans.* bzw. *intrans.* – Das bedeutet, dass man diese Worte im Passiv verwenden darf oder nicht.

Comment: Ist es nicht eher anders herum? "Der Spaß wird von uns gehabt" ist zwar schön, aber nicht erlaubt, denn "Wir haben viel Spaß" ist intransitiv?